How to use RoundRobinLoadBalancer "round_robin" in Java grpc 1.64.0?
I have updated grpc from 1.58.0 to 1.64.0 and the RoundRobinLoadBalancer is gone. Where did it go?
Is there an alternative?
I simply tried using the "pick_first" load balancer, but that's not what I want.
Thanks in advance.

Are you making a fat/uber for your application? It may be a "bug" in your build process. If so, what tool are you using to make the jar?

It is still there in HEAD, so it has not been removed from 1.64.0: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/util/src/main/java/io/grpc/util/RoundRobinLoadBalancer.java

Found a solution by importing the io.grpc:grpc-util:1.64.0 dependency:
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import io.grpc.LoadBalancer;
import io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider;
import io.grpc.util.RoundRobinLoadBalancer;

@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "create")
public final class RoundRobinLoadBalancerProvider extends LoadBalancerProvider {
  @Override
  public boolean isAvailable() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int getPriority() {
    return 10;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPolicyName() {
    return "round_robin";
  }

  @Override
  public LoadBalancer newLoadBalancer(LoadBalancer.Helper helper) {
    return new RoundRobinLoadBalancer(helper);
  }
}

